# How to correctly use Javascript 'this' in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a following (simplified) code:

```
var myModule = {

    submitDummyForm: function(){ 
        console.log(this); // the right object is logged out
        var that = this; // keep a reference
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/',
            data: {dummyData: 'something'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: that.dummyFormSuccess

        });
    },

    dummyFormSuccess: function(data){ 
        console.log(this); // 'this' is logged out as some foreign object, most probably jQuery.ajax object
    }
}
```

It leads to 'this' being lost in the dummyFormSuccess, no matter if I use this.dummyFormSuccess or that.dummyFormSuccessfor as an argument for my ajaxSubmitForm().

But the following code gets executed as I need:

```
var myModule = {

    submitDummyForm: function(){ 
        console.log(this); // the right object is logged out
        var that = this; // keep a reference
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/',
            data: {dummyData: 'something'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                 that.dummyFormSuccess(data);
            }
        });
    },

    dummyFormSuccess: function(data){ 
       console.log(this); // now 'this' is logged out correctly as the real myModule object
    }
}
```

I'm still not very comfortable with advanced topics of Javascript but I already know, that 'this' may get redefined, depending on where it is used. I thought if I use 'that' to store the reference to 'this', it should also keep my 'this' inside the called function.  It seems weird, that I can call that.dummyFormSuccess(data) in a wrap-around function and it gets correct 'this' inside, but if I just assign it to $.ajax success, my 'this' gets lost.

Can anybody explain, where is 'this' getting lost in my case and why it works OK in the second example? Is it a problem with jQuery (maybe jQuery.ajax() overwrites my 'this' somehow in my case) or just a feature of the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct. Your `this` is lost in a first example because you are **assigning** function `that.dummyFormSuccess` to jQuery `ajax` object's `success`. So, this way, deep inside jQuery, it's called something like `ajax.success`. So, `this` is overwritten with `ajax` object.

With second approach you create an anonymous function and assgn it to `success`. So inside your anonymous function, `this` points to `ajax` object, but `that` variable is accessible and have not been overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding `this`.

The value of `this` parameter is determined by the *callsite* – the code that calls your function.
When you pass `that.dummyFormSuccess` or `this.dummyFormSuccess`, you're just passing a function that happens to come from your object.
The `this` or `that` object is just used to retrieve the function instance; it isn't bundled with the function.

When jQuery calls your callback, it always calls it in the context of the jqXHR object.
When you pass `function(data) { that.dummyFormSuccess(data); }`, your function expression is called in the context of this jqXHR object.
However, your callback then calls `dummyFormSuccess` in the context of `that`, so its `this` is what you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat 'this' in JavaScript as additional argument in function argument list. 
So each call of function will contain its own value in `this` argument. Here are all three ways of invoking function in JS

- `foo();` - inside the function `this` will be set to default
  namespace object (window in case of browser environment).
- `obj.foo();` - `this` will get `obj` reference inside the foo().
- `foo.call(obj);` - 'foo' will be called with `this` set to `obj` (same as above)

Answer (score 0):

Since a function can also mean an object (and it is an object), `this` means that function. (different scopes)

What you need to do is put `var that = this;` outside of `dummyForm : function` (the line above it), and then do `console.log(that)`.

```
var that = this;
dummyFormSuccess: function(data){ 
   console.log(that); // now 'this' is logged out correctly as the real myModule object
}
```

Comment: Wrong.  `this` does not mean the function.